In Flask JWT Extended, when revoking both access and refresh Tokens, shouldn't I also revoke access of the last non-fresh token?
After reading the documentation, it was clear to me that the client should send two request to the /logout endpoint, as it says in this example using Redis as the hosted blocklist:
@app.route("/logout", methods=["DELETE"])
@jwt_required(verify_type=False)
def logout():
    token = get_jwt()
    jti = token["jti"]
    ttype = token["type"]
    jwt_redis_blocklist.set(jti, "", ex=ACCESS_EXPIRES)

    # Returns "Access token revoked" or "Refresh token revoked"
    return jsonify(msg=f"{ttype.capitalize()} token successfully revoked")

But then I realized: What about the last non-fresh token? The last token created by the refresh-token?
I'm aware that the validity of that token should not be long, but I assume that in a safe system it should also be blocklisted.
So, should I make a third DELETE request?
Thanks.

Keep in mind that the actual design concept of JWTs is not to verify the token against a central source, neither positively nor negatively. So the idea of revoking it is against the design already, independent of if you revoke one or all tokens of a user.
